# Should "one time" contributions update membership status/renewal or be separate?

Tags: civimember, contributions, civirules, automation

Web contractor for mid-sized NPO here. Staff wants contributions of a certain amount to effect a contact's membership. For example, annual membership is $100 a year, Bob has a membership and makes a contribution for $150. The idea is to make the $150 contribution count towards Bob's membership by automatically renewing it for 1 year based on the donation amount.

Is there a solution "out there" for this? Is there a reason to caution against this idea?

Comment: I am not sure of this but I *think* you could use CiviRules to trigger a membership renewal for any contribution over a specific amount. You could make a membership type for it (e.g., "Donation member") so that when membership staff look at their data they can distinguish between people who intentionally renewed and those who renewed via donation. The only caution I have is from a process/program perspective--do you want to consider people members if they may not have intentionally joined the org? This may not matter for the type of org you are but if it does it is a significant question.

Comment: @LisaJ, Thanks for your response. I agree with your caution about people who may want to keep membership and donations separate. It's a tricky workflow because they want all donations of any amount to count towards the membership fee. So 10 $10 donations should trigger a $100 membership renewal. I may just say "no" but I wanted to bounce the idea around. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that part from your initial question. Maybe you could set up a CiviRule that triggers a when total donations over a period of time triggers the renewal. But then your program folks need to decide when the membership should start (with the first donation? the last one? a middle one?).